# event on the object in the iframe

Tags: jquery

how to put the event on the object in the iframe, using jquery .

I have Iframe 
html:

```
<iframe name="users" width="220" height="510" align="left" 
src='messages/users.php'></iframe>
```

and in this iframe I have a link

```
<a class="link" href=""></a>
```

So I'm trying to write jquery script that do some actions when you click that link
I'm tried to use `.contents().find("body").onclick` but it is doesn't work, probably i made somewhere mistake,
And even tried to use just

```
$(document).on('click',".link", function () 
        {});
```

- but it is defenetly desn't work because it is iframe
      May be I need use DOM somehow, like in javscript parent.document.getElementById ?

user.php

```
     <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta content="10; url=users.php?login=<?=$login;? "HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh>
</head>
<body>  
    <?php
printf(" <p><a href=\"\" class=\"link\" id=\"".$line."\">".$row['Login']."</a></p>");?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the problem in load function $('#user').load(function(){
 alert ("here"); }); doesn't give me  the result

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [jQuery load method](http://api.jquery.com/load/), Use the below code and try.

```
$(function () {
$('iframe').load(function() {
    $(this).contents().find("body")
        .on('click', function(event) {
            alert('test');
    });
})
})
```